# Server Error ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Logs show app is looking for "posts" but the partial I'm using on the index page is "post":

```
<div id="posts">
  <h2>Here are the latest posts</h2>
    <%= render 'post' %>
</div>
```

Here's the log entry:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial posts/_posts
```

At one time I was using posts/_posts, but I change the it to posts/_post. Where might this call be made, other than where I call for the partial on the index page? The partial is in the same PostsController.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your partial is under `posts/_post`, you want to use `<%= render partial: 'post' %>`.

Comment: Tried that to no avail. I changed everything back to "posts/posts" and the error vanished. I still would like to know where that call came from even after I had changed everything to "posts/post"

Comment: did you name the file `_post.html.erb`?

Comment: Yes, it was named _post.html.erb in the views/posts folder (But I have since renamed it _posts.html.erb

Comment: So if the file is named `_posts.html.erb` you'd need `<%= render partial: 'posts' %>`. And the file should be under the `views/posts` directory.